Testing async method with pytest does not show calls to patched method
I'm currently writing some tests for a FastAPI middleware component using pytest. This component is a class-type middleware and works exactly as it should, very happy with it. However, when writing tests I'm trying to execute the dispatch method within the component to then make assertions on the output (I'll attach the rest of the setup code below, here is the important part):
import asyncio

pytest_plugins = ("pytest_asyncio",)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="cache_service_table_get_mock")
def fixture_cache_service_table_get_mock(mocker: MockerFixture):
    mock_table = mocker.patch("api.utils.cache_middleware.dynamo.table")

    mock_table.get_item.return_value = {"Items": []}
    mock_table.put_item.return_value = None

    yield mock_table

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_cache_no_hit(cache_service_table_get_mock: MagicMock):
    cache = CacheMiddleware(app)
    request = create_request({"query": "some random query", "product_code": "dummy"})
    result = await cache.dispatch(request=request, call_next=mock_call_next)

    assert result.status_code == 200
    assert result.body == json.dumps({"answer": "dummy response"}, indent=2).encode(
        "utf-8"
    )
    # This generates an error indicating that call_count is 0
    assert cache_service_table_get_mock.get_item.call_count == 1 

I am 100% sure that the get_item mock is getting called and that it returns the expected mocked value (both by adding print statements everywhere in the cache.dispatch method and because the second assert would only hold it this was the case).
Is there something missing for the call_count property to update correctly?

Remaining setup code
import json
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest
from fastapi import Request, Response
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from api import app
from api.utils.cache_middleware import CacheMiddleware

client = TestClient(app)

# Class used to mock the body_iterator prop used in the cache middleware
class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.length = 1
        self.item = item

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.length == 0:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.length -= 1
        return self.item

    pass


async def mock_call_next(request: Request) -> Response:
    content = json.dumps({"answer": "dummy response"}, indent=2).encode("utf-8")
    response = Response(
        content=content,
        status_code=200,
        headers=request.headers,
        media_type="text",
    )
    body_iterator = AsyncIterator(content)
    response.__dict__["body_iterator"] = body_iterator

    return response


def create_request(body):
    request = Request(
        scope={
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "test.com/customapi",
            "body": body,
            "type": "http",
            "path": "/customapi",
            "headers": {},
        }
    )

    async def receive():
        return {
            "type": "http.request",
            "body": json.dumps(body, indent=2).encode("utf-8"),
        }

    request._receive = receive
    return request

I have tried using the assert_called_once method with the same result.
I have tried using the same method but for an unrelated non-async function and this works correctly.
I have tried only mocking one method in my fixture with the same result.
It honestly feels like I'm missing something obvious from the documentation that I've been unable to find. Appreciate any help

It seems like the issue is related to how magicmock handles asynchronous functions. Since get_item might be an asynchronous function in your middleware, using magicmock to mock it could lead to unusual or unexpected behavior when checking for call counts. It is best to use AsyncMock instead, which is designed to work with async functions.
Solution
Use AsyncMock for the get_item method like this:
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
@pytest.fixture(scope = "function", name = "cache_service_table_get_mock")
def fixture_cache_service_table_get_mock(mocker: MockerFixture):
    mock_table = 
    mocker.patch("api.utils.cache_middleware.dynamo.table", autospec = True)
    mock_table.get_item = AsyncMock(return_value = { "Items": [] })
    mock_table.put_item = AsyncMock(return_value = None)

    yield mock_table

Test: check for await_count instead of call_count
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_cache_no_hit(cache_service_table_get_mock):
    cache = CacheMiddleware(app)
    request = create_request({ "query": "some random query", "product_code": "dummy" })
    result = await cache.dispatch(request = request, call_next=mock_call_next)

    assert result.status_code == 200
    assert result.body == json.dumps({ "answer": "dummy response" }, indent = 2).encode("utf-8")
    # Check await_count for async methods
    assert cache_service_table_get_mock.get_item.await_count == 1 


I tried this but it didn't quite work. I'm now getting that await_count is 0. Worth noting that the database methods themselves aren't defined as async (even though they do call a database service), it is only the FastAPI middleware dispatch method.
